# How to deselect a selected UITableView cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, interface-builder

I am working on a project on which I have to preselect a particular cell.

I can preselect a cell using `-willDisplayCell`, but I can't deselect it when the user clicks on any other cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView 
        willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell
        forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{ 
    AppDelegate_iPad *appDelegte = 
      (AppDelegate_iPad *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if ([appDelegte.indexPathDelegate row] == [indexPath row])
    {
        [cell setSelected:YES];    
    } 
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
        didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    AppDelegate_iPad *appDelegte = 
      (AppDelegate_iPad *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSIndexPath *indexpath1 = appDelegte.indexPathDelegate;
    appDelegte.indexPathDelegate = indexPath;
    [materialTable deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexpath1 animated:NO];
}
```

Can you help?

Comment: This question need to have an accepted answer

Answer (score 436):

use this code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {
    //Change the selected background view of the cell.
     [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
 }
```

### Swift 3.0:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //Change the selected background view of the cell.
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: There is a didDeselectRowAtIndexPath to use to deselect the previous one.

Comment: I like to think I can't upvote this post because it would cause an integer overflow :)

Comment: hi @ram, you need to select an answer on this question

Comment: I don't understand... this code is never going to let anything get selected.

Comment: @matrixugly is right. It's more appropriate to do this inside `willSelectRowAt:`. See a more complete answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693402/uitableview-tap-to-deselect-cell

Answer (score 119):

Use the following method in the table view delegate's `didSelectRowAtIndexpath` (Or from anywhere)

```
[myTable deselectRowAtIndexPath:[myTable indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `indexPathForSelectedRow` is a method and not a property.

Comment: Sweet!  Didn't know about `[myTable indexPathForSelectedRow]`.  I was looping through the cells before.  Thanks!

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer Is this distinction important somehow? Property accessors are methods.

Comment: @chaiguy That's fine if you don't mind your colleagues considering you [evil](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2375991/632736).

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer But even if it is a method call, all its doing is retrieving one value - not going to affect performance right? Even on the slowest of devices.

Comment: @Supertecnoboff There is no difference in performance between the two variations.

Answer (score 44):

It might be useful to make an extension in Swift for this.

**Swift 4 and Swift 5:**

Swift extension (e.g. in a UITableViewExtension.swift file):

```
import UIKit

extension UITableView {

    func deselectSelectedRow(animated: Bool)
    {
        if let indexPathForSelectedRow = self.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            self.deselectRow(at: indexPathForSelectedRow, animated: animated)
        }
    }

}
```

Use e.g.:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.tableView.deselectSelectedRow(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, this answer is better because putting the desolation in the `viewWillAppear()` method helps the user to understand where he comes back from.

Comment: the perfect one as i needed

Answer (score 40):

Try this:

```
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows) {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Good job...  I think 'index' on the 2nd line should be indexPath

Comment: this is not supported on iOS 11 Swift 4

Answer (score 28):

Please check with the delegate method whether it is correct or not. For example;

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

for

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Was calling the wrong method this whole time, arghh!! Thank you!

Comment: oh man.... bloody autocompletion!!! It took me several hours to figure it out!!! OMG...I want to kiss you!

Answer (score 26):

Swift 4:

```
tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
```

Comment: Doesn't need to be declared non-optional but this is correct.

Answer (score 23):

This is a solution for Swift 4

```
 in tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

just add

```
tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
```

it works like a charm

example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
//some code
}
```

Comment: until you add selection on editing in your tableview, it will be impossible to select any cell because it will deselect it when you done selecting it :)

Comment: This is certainly the correct approach, when you're not editing, when you're "tapping a row to do something"

Answer (score 11):

In addition to setting the cell as selected, you also need to inform the tableView that the cell is selected. Add a call to `-tableView:selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` to your `willDisplayCell:` method: and you will be able to deselect it as normal.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView 
  willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{ 
    AppDelegate_iPad *appDelegte = (AppDelegate_iPad *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if ([appDelegte.indexPathDelegate row] == [indexPath row])
    {
        // SELECT CELL
        [cell setSelected:YES]; 
        // TELL TABLEVIEW THAT ROW IS SELECTED
        [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];   
    } 
}
```

Be sure to use UITableViewScrollPositionNone to avoid odd scrolling behavior.

Comment: Absolutely correct. I think that `[cell setSelected:YES]` could be omitted: `selectRowAtIndexPath` will take care of the cell's `selected` state

Comment: This answer works for UITableView's with multiple selections. Thumbs up.

Answer (score 7):

Based on saikirans solution, I have written this, which helped me. On the .m file:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(selectedRowIndex && indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex.row) {

        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        selectedRowIndex = nil;

    }

    else {  self.selectedRowIndex = [indexPath retain];   }

    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];

}
```

And on the header file:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSIndexPath* selectedRowIndex;
```

I am not very experienced either, so double check for memory leaks etc.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to select any table cell with the first click and deselect with the second, you should use this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
        didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {   

    if (self.selectedIndexPath && 
        [indexPath compare:self.selectedIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {

        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
         self.selectedIndexPath = nil;
    } 
    else {
        self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Swift 4:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    if cell?.isSelected == true { // check if cell has been previously selected
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        return nil
    } else {
        return indexPath
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me in Swift 3. Just had to add `self.tableView(tableView, didDeselectRowAt: indexPath)` after `tableView.deselectRow...` because it was not called automatically

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexpath1 animated:NO];
```

Just make sure materialTable and tableView are pointing to the same object.

Is materials connected to the tableView in Interface Builder?

Comment: i have tested with NO but that also not solve my problem. but i fixed this issue with another way as reloaded Data when ever the didselect delegate fired.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 2.0:

```
tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3/4**

In ViewController:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

In Custom Cell:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    selectionStyle = .none
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
```

Comment: try explaining your answer, else it should be a comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSIndexPath * index = [self.menuTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
[self.menuTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:index animated:NO];
```

place this code according to your code and you will get your cell deselected.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
  didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    AppDelegate_iPad *appDelegte = 
    (AppDelegate_iPad *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSIndexPath *indexpath1 = appDelegte.indexPathDelegate;
    appDelegte.indexPathDelegate = indexPath;

    UITableViewCell *prevSelectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexpath1];
    if([prevSelectedCell isSelected]){
       [prevSelectedCell setSelected:NO];
    }
}
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    // your code

    // your code

    // and use deselect row to end line of this function

    self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3.0:**

Following the [protocol conformance section of the ray wenderlich swift style guide](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#protocol-conformance), to keep related methods grouped together, put this extension below your view controller class like that:

```
// your view controller
class MyViewcontroller: UIViewController {
  // class stuff here
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate
extension MyViewcontroller: UITableViewDelegate {
      // use the UITableViewDelegate method tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // your code when user select row at indexPath

        // at the end use deselectRow
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3

I've run into this as well - when you navigate or unwind back to the table view it usually doesn't deselect the previously selected row for you. I put this code in the table view controller & it works well:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if let lastSelectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: lastSelectedRow, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**swift 3.0**

```
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

To have deselect (DidDeselectRowAt) fire when clicked the first time because of preloaded data; you need inform the tableView that the row is already selected to begin with, so that an initial click then deselects the row:

//Swift 3:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView[indexPath.row] == "data value"

        tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)

    }
}
```