# UITableView tap to deselect cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` that is selected when tapped. During this selected state, if the user taps the cell again, I want the cell to deselect.

I can't find any of the delegate calls being hit. Any ideas how to implement this? Is it really going to be a gesture recognizer?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Maybe my question wasn't specific enough, but the two answers are a bit wide of what I was after.

It seems this isn't possible, and I went with a gesture recognizer of the cell to manually set selected / unselected state.

Comment: What do you really want to do? My code give you ability to track that cell has been selected before or not. Inside that if statement you can implement more stuff you want.

Comment: It's easy. How many cell do you have? I can write you a sample code with one cell by using UItableview delegate. Let me know if you still interest.

Comment: It is definitely possible, please change to @prisonerjohn 's answer as the correct one as it is exactly what your question describes.

Comment: I don't understand, what for do we have a delegate method if we need to do a circus to get that delegate method called?

Answer (score 39):

You can actually do this using the delegate method `willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([cell isSelected]) {
        // Deselect manually.
        [tableView.delegate tableView:tableView willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        [tableView.delegate tableView:tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        return nil;
    }

    return indexPath;
}
```

Note that `deselectRowAtIndexPath:` won't call the delegate methods automatically, so you need to make those calls manually.

Comment: Note that you should always check if the delegate responds to a selector before calling a method on it.

Answer (score 30):

in Swift 4:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {

    if let indexPathForSelectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow,
        indexPathForSelectedRow == indexPath {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
        return nil
    }
    return indexPath
}
```

Comment: Requires an "override" and it can be confusing if you don't call the delegate methods by hand (willDeselect... and didDeselect...)

Answer (score 6):

When using "Multiple Selection" mode, "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" will not be called when you click a row that is already selected.  More than one row can still be selected programatically in "Single Selection" mode and the rows will trigger didSelectRowAtIndexPath on all clicks.

Just a heads up to anyone who was having the same problems.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an even cleaner solution:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] isEqual:indexPath]) {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        return nil;
    }
    return indexPath;
}
```

Comment: Don't use == for comparison of objects. This should be     if ([[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] isEqual: indexPath]) {

Answer (score 4):

Leave the single selection mode on, but override the following funcs like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    if tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.contains(indexPath) ?? false {
       tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
       return nil
    }

    return indexPath
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    return nil
}
```

Comment: This one works perfectly, it should be accepted answer. Point to note is that Tableview should be set to Single selection mode as mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

When you select a cell this delegate method is triggered.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


        UITableViewCell *theUITableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
        if (theUITableViewCell.selected == YES){
            self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:<#(NSIndexPath *)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#>
            // Do more thing
        }else{
            // By default, it is highlighted for selected state
        }

 }
```

It's pseudo code.

Answer (score 3):

I think that using the blue selection colouring for toggling may give a strange impression. Why not use an accessory like a checkmark? This is a much more familiar technique for selection toggling (be it multi-cell or single-cell).

See this answer for info:
[UITableView Multiple Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040894/uitableview-multiple-selection)

Answer (score 3):

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([cell isSelected]) {
        // Deselect manually.
        if ([tableView.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:)]) {
            [tableView.delegate tableView:tableView willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        if ([tableView.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:)]) {
            [tableView.delegate tableView:tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
        return nil;
    }

    return indexPath;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one, it's works for me (for single selection or multiple selections):

A. allocate a private NSMutableArray in viewDidLoad like:

```
@interface XXXViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray * selectedZoneCellIndexPaths;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    selectedZoneCellIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

B. in UITableViewDelegate didSelectRow add following lines

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     for (NSIndexPath * iter in selectedZoneCellIndexPaths)
     {
         if (indexPath.section == iter.section && indexPath.row == iter.row)
         {
             [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
             [selectedZoneCellIndexPaths removeObject:iter];
             return;
         }
     }
     [selectedZoneCellIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
     return;
}
```

Comment: This will cause bugs if you don't handle dequeuing of cells correctly

Answer (score 1):

Swift version of prisonerjohn's answer :

```
public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
  let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
  if (cell?.selected ?? false) {
    // Deselect manually.
    tableView.delegate!.tableView?(tableView, willDeselectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    tableView.delegate!.tableView?(tableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    return nil
  }
return indexPath;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From @prisonerjohn, in case someone wonders how to check if the delegate responds to the selector as @Patrick said, in **Swift 3**:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else {
        // Handle invalid cell
        ...
    }

    if cell.isSelected {
        if let respond = tableView.delegate?.responds(
            to: #selector(tableView(_:willDeselectRowAt:))),
            respond == true {
            tableView.delegate?.tableView!(tableView, willDeselectRowAt: indexPath)
        }

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        if let respond = tableView.delegate?.responds(
            to: #selector(tableView(_:didDeselectRowAt:))),
            respond == true {
            tableView.delegate?.tableView!(tableView, didDeselectRowAt: indexPath)
        }

        return nil
    }

    return indexPath
}
```

Comment: I get the following error: `Use of unresolved identifier 'tableView(_:willDeselectRowAt:)'`. Using XCode9.1 and Swift3

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5.

In the `UITableViewDelegate`, it's as simple as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was after the same thing but @occulus' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693402/uitableview-tap-to-deselect-cell/12693827#12693827) provided me the hint I was missing.

It made me realize the way to get this done is to allow multiple selection in the table view and manually deselect previously selected rows when a new row is selected using one of the delegate methods.

It seems quite natural that in single selection mode, the table view tries to leave one row selected as much as possible, thus not deselecting on tapping a selected row.