# didDeselectRowAt never called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView, where the **UITableViewDelegate is set** like this:

```
    tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
```

In the delegate I implement (among others) the functions

- `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`
- `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

My custom Cell that inherits from `UITableViewCell` overrides `setSelected` this way:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    if selected {
        // visual updates (with a small animation)
    } else {
        // visual updates
    }
}
```

**The Problem** is that, when tapping on the cell, `didSelectRowAt` is always called and never `didDeselectRowAt`, hence, the cell always is shown as selected. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: @Pipiks My selectionStyle is not set to `.none`

Comment: try     tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
in didSelectRowAt

Comment: That would cause the cell to always be deselected

Comment: turn on the multiple cell selection

Comment: I was calling `reloadData()`, using `reloadRows(at:,with:)` instead solved the problem

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693402/uitableview-tap-to-deselect-cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement this:

```
yourTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
```

In your didSelectRowAt method or in your didDeselectRowAt method.

Hope this is helpful :)

Comment: I do something similar by calling `super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)` in my custom cell. Calling `deselectRow` in `didDeselectRowAt` would cause an infinite loop. Calling it in `didSelectRowAt` would cause the cell to always be deselected.

Comment: So you want select your row then did something and then deselect it? right?

Comment: on tap when it is selected it should deselect. If it was deselected before it should select.

Comment: @Daniel ok like the keyboard when you tap off it?