# How can I unselect my row selected in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cell

I want deselect a row previously selected selecting this again. I only can deselected this row clicking in other row but I want deselect this clicking on this again. How can I do this?

This is my code:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
[self updateTableView];
 }

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
[self updateTableView];
}


 - (void)updateTableView
{
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: please check before posting a question if something related is present or not.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968037/how-to-deselect-a-selected-uitableview-cell

Answer (score 1):

Track the selected index path using a property. Within `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` compare your stored index path to the index path provided in the delegate method. If they are the same, it means the row was already selected. Call `deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:` to deselect it and set your stored index path to nil. Otherwise, update the stored index path to the index path provided in the delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

There is a deselectRowAtIndexPath method in the tableviews. Use that method passing your indexpath.