# Dot notation in objective-c

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a Java program I am converting into objective-c.

In Java I uses dot notation and for for example have the following line of code:

```
this.m_root.computeGlobalTransforms();
```

Which calls a method called computeGlobalTransforms().

Am I able to use dot notation like this in objective-c or will I need to write the line as and pass 'm_root' as an object:

```
[self computeGlobalTransforms:m_root];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `computeGlobalTransforms` is an instance method of the class `m_root` object, and if `m_root` is a class property of `self`, then the syntax is:

```
[self.m_root computeGlobalTransforms].
```

I'd suggest you refer to [Methods and Messaging](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/) in *Learning Objective-C: A Primer.*

---

If `computeGlobalTransforms` is a `VA_Bone` method, the syntax would be:

```
VA_Bone *bone = [[VA_Bone alloc] init];
[bone computeGlobalTransforms];
```

Your `bone` variable is a simple local variable, thus no reference to `self.m_root` is needed.

---

By the way, as a matter of convention, the underscores in the middle of variable and class names is generally not used. See [Naming Properties and Data Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html) in the *Coding Guidelines for Cocoa.* Also see references to "camel case" in the [Conventions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html) of *Programming with Objective-C.*

Thus, a more common naming convention would be `VABone` for your class. Likewise for your original `m_root` property that you alluded to, you'd (a) give it a more descriptive name; and (b) use camel case. Now I don't know what the "m" of `m_root` is supposed to stand for (which, alone, illustrates the problem), but let's say it it was for medium sized images, then it might be `mediumSizedImagesRoot`, or whatever.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the following code:         
        VA_Bone *bone   =   [[VA_Bone alloc] init];
        
        [self.m_root [bone computeGlobalTransforms]]; I want to call the method computeGlobalTransforms which is found in a class called Bone on the self.m_root object. This does not appear to work, what have I done wrong?

Comment: @samb90 See my revised answer.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* use dot notation to call zero parameter methods. You absolutely shouldn't. Dot notation is handled by the compiler, rather than the run time - there's a very good answer to a similar question that talks about why it works, and why you shouldn't use it (...for anything other than setters/getters) here:

[Objective-C dot notation with class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375943/objective-c-2-0-dot-notation-class-methods)

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, you can only use Dot.Notation for setters and getters for your properties.

Comment: That's not the case - it's terrible style to use it for anything other than properties though: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2375991/197143